# python-eve custom media storage file upload not working

Tags: storage, media, eve

I am trying to build a python-eve REST API with mysql backend and I would like to have a custom mediastorage backend. Basicly I want the filenames saved into database and files in filesystem.

Here is a draft of the mediastorage based on the GridFS in the core:

```py
class CustomMediaStorage(MediaStorage):

    def __init__(self, app=None):

        super(CustomMediaStorage, self).__init__(app)

        self.validate()

    def validate(self):

        if self.app is None:
            raise TypeError('Application object cannot be None')

        if not isinstance(self.app, Flask):
            raise TypeError('Application object must be a Eve application')

    def get(self, path, resource=None):

        pprint(path)

        _file = None

        try:
            _file = open(path, 'r') 
        except:
            pass
        return _file

    def post(self, content, filename=None, content_type=None, resource=None):

        pprint('post')

        if(filename):

            path = 'var/www/koodit/upload/'+filename

            try:
                _file = open(path, 'w') 
                _file.write(content)
                _file.close()
            except:
                pass

        return path
```

My specific problem here is that while the class catches the get-method the post-method does not seem to be able even to print out the comment.

Calling the media storage this way:

```py
app = Eve(data=SQL,settings=SETTINGS, media=CustomMediaStorage)
```

From client side I tried to send the image as base64.

"file was expected, got 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/7QCEUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMu...
instead.",

Comment: This is old, but with eve 0.7 the name of the function in MediaStorage to implement to retrieve files is `put` not `post`.